# Servicestack OrmLite Ignore insert update - POCO

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is there any attribute set a POCO field just for SELECT.

Something like below;

```
public class Poco {
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     [IgnoreUpdate]
     public Datetime CreatedOn{ get; set; }
     [IgnoreInsert]
     public Datetime UpdateOn{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrmLite has `[Ignore]` to ignore the property completely, `[IgnoreOnInsert]` to ignore the property during INSERT's and `[IgnoreOnUpdate]` to ignore the property during updates.

An alternative solution is to use a different Model for SELECT's where you can use the `[Alias]` attribute to map it back to the original tablename, e.g.

```
[Alias("Poco")]
public class PocoDetails
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Datetime CreatedOn{ get; set; }
    public Datetime UpdateOn{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just small update - in current verion of ServiceStack v5 there is possibility to mark property with attributes `[IgnoreOnInsert]`, `[IgnoreOnUpdate]` or `[IgnoreOnSelect]`